# Does anyone know how to grab this specific value using cheerio (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

`<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-ID-numbers" value="form-value-numbers"  />`

I'm trying to grab the following using cheerio. However, I keep getting undefined. I want to include the name because there are other input tags as well, but I want to grab this specific one. The name is unique. Thanks for the help :)

I tried using the following and it keeps giving me 'undefined':

```
$('input[name="form_build_id"]').val();
```

Comment: Not much we can do here without seeing a lot more context.  That is a proper selector so likely the issue is something else besides just that.  Are you 100% sure the form is there in the HTML you're using and that it's not added by Javascript?  Can you retrieve anything from that form?  Like the form tag itself?

Comment: @gio have you tried this `$('input[name=form_build_id]').val()` remove double quotes from `name` attribute??

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to scrape the following page: view-source:https://www.jimmyjazz.com/cart/checkout . If you search for form_build_id it shows what I'm trying to scrape. I'm trying to select the attribute 'value' value. The values inside the original post attributes aren't the exact ones in the actual html (made it shorter).

Comment: @Sanoj_V yes, that solution didn't work for me

Comment: When I do a view source on that page, I do not see that element in the page.   There is one form in the page, but it does not have the element you're looking for in it.  Could it be that I'm not logged in?  Could it be that your node.js client isn't logged in (e.g. doesn't have the right login cookie)?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I just realized this is the issue. I need a way to get the cookie. I tested manually, and what you seen when clicking the link isn't the correct page I get. You can only access the page I'm trying to scrape from if you have something in cart. The way I'm doing this in my script is by sending 2 different get request to different URL's. However, I'm not getting the cookie for the 2nd one, and this is why my selector isn't working. (Fairly new to web scraping).

Comment: If you want help with the cookie, show us the code for the two requests you're using to try to get the page with.  We can't help with code we can't see.  Are you logging in?  Are you preserving cookies with a cookie jar with your request code?  Can't help fix your code if we can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

When I go to [that URL](https://www.jimmyjazz.com/cart/checkout) and then do a View/Source (which should give me the same HTML that cheerio will get), there is only one form and there is no element like what you're looking for in it.  So, that's likely why your cheerio code can't get it - it isn't there.

Assuming you are seeing the right data in your View/Source and since it appears you're looking for info from a view/cart page, you would have to have the right login cookie in order to have access to the right data.  So, if you're seeing the target form element when you do View/Source in your browser, then the issue would be that you don't have the right login cookie being sent with your node.js request.

You will need to get the right login cookie to send with your nodejs request.  That means either logging in via nodejs and capturing that cookie (perhaps with a cookie jar) or somehow manually grabbing the cookie and then including it with your request.